# Spring JPA - two way mapping fetch child eagerly

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, eager-loading, two-way-binding

I have two Class

Parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_FILTER_TYPE")
public class ReportFilterType {
    public ReportFilterType() {}

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "FILTER_TYPE_ID",nullable=false)
    private int filterTypeId;

    @Column(name = "FILTER_TYPE")
    private String filterType;

    @Column(name = "FILTER_NAME")
    private String filterName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportFilterType"  )  
    //@JsonIgnore
    public Set<ReportFilterOperators> reportFilterOperators; 
}
```

Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_FILTER_OPERATORS")
public class ReportFilterOperators {
    public ReportFilterOperators() {}

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "FILTER_OPR_ID",nullable=false)
    private int filterOprId;

    @Column(name = "FILTER_TYPE_ID")
    private int filterTypeId;

    @Column(name = "FILTER_OPR_VALUE")
    private String filterOprValue;



 @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn (name="FILTER_TYPE_ID",referencedColumnName="FILTER_TYPE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
      public ReportFilterType reportFilterType;  
}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface ReportFilterTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ReportFilterType, Integer>{

    List<ReportFilterType> findAll();   
    }
```

when i try to use spring JPA findALL method to load child early the Objects are getting loaded recursively

if i add `@JsonIgnore` in the parent then it works but not getting child loaded.

Can i know how i can get the parent Object with the child loaded  ?

Comment: try adding cascade specification to the owner side @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportFilterType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: also you might need fetch specification since OneToMany is lazy fetching by default 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportFilterType", fetch=FetchType.EAGER ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: owner* -> owned